# Get element with computed style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of elements with `position: fixed` in my page. How do I perform a loop through these elements?

Something like:

```
$('body').find([all elements with position == fixed]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("position") === 'fixed';
});
```

The function will go through each element and checks for the condition to be satisfied. If it is `fixed`, then it returns `true`. The `filter()` function is an add-on to the `$()` selector to select only the elements that satisfy the condition.

If the above doesn't work, you can also use this:

```
$('*').filter(function () {
    return this.style && this.style.position === 'fixed'
});
```

Reason for the above code:

The `.css()` is jQuery's function, which works on the jQuery object. Creating a jQuery object from the native object, and running a jQuery function on the jQuery object can be time consuming and performance intensive than the native functions.

Comment: @light `.css()` is jQuery's function, which works on the jQuery object. Creating a jQuery object from the native object, and running a jQuery function on the jQuery object can be time consuming and performance hungry than the native functions. Do you agree?

Comment: jQuery is of course less efficient than native, but that's besides the point since the OP is using jQuery. You suggested that `.css()` could fail, and provided an alternative that also uses jQuery. But I don't understand how `.css()` would fail.

Comment: It wouldn't fail, sorry, but the browser might fail! `:P`